# Hide the class if the value of varible is null in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to hide the class `.abc` if the `res.Website` is null.

```
<div id='abc">
  <div id="abcd">WEBSITE</div>
  <div id="ccc">{{res.Website}}</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `ng-class` like: `<div class="ng-class: {abcd: res.Website == null}">WEBSITE</div>`. Make sure you take a look at the documentation first: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-hide and give condition `res.Website==null`

```
<div id="abc" ng-hide="{{res.Website==null}}">
     <div id="abcd">WEBSITE</div>
     <div id="ccc">{{res.Website}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show for this case:

```
<div id='abc" ng-show="{{res.Website}}">
    <div id="abcd">WEBSITE</div>
    <div id="ccc">{{res.Website}}</div>
</div>
```